# Xamarin Forms Label inside Frame not showing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a Frame in my page using this code:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="#212121">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="20, 0, 20, 0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Source="Logo.png" HeightRequest="200" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="30" />
        <Entry Grid.Row="1" Placeholder="Username" PlaceholderColor="#bababa" FontSize="16" x:Name="txtUsername" TextColor="White" />
        <Entry Grid.Row="2" Placeholder="Email" PlaceholderColor="#bababa" FontSize="16" x:Name="txtEmail" TextColor="White" />
        <Entry Grid.Row="3" Placeholder="Password" PlaceholderColor="#bababa" FontSize="16" IsPassword="True" x:Name="txtPassword" TextColor="White" TextChanged="OnPasswordTextChanged" />

        <Frame Grid.Row="4" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" x:Name="FramePasswordStrength" >
            <Label Text="Test" BackgroundColor="Purple" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="txtPasswordStrength" FontSize="14" />
        </Frame>

        <Entry Grid.Row="5" Placeholder="Confirm Password" PlaceholderColor="#bababa" FontSize="16" IsPassword="True" x:Name="txtConfirmPassword" TextColor="White" />
        <Button Text="Sign up" FontAttributes="Bold" Clicked="btnRegisterClicked" BackgroundColor="#3897F0" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="6" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that my frame get drawn the way I want, but there is no label in the center of that Frame. Now I already tried to reduce the FontSize, but that doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works fine for me.  Have you tried any normal troubleshooting steps - rebooting, restarting VS, cleaning/rebuilding your solution, etc?

Comment: also, have you tried explicitly setting the background color of the label?

Comment: Yep, just tried all of your suggested options. Hold on, I will give you the full code!

Comment: I added the full code to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />` to row's height so it should has the correct height for all controls.

You can also set Frame's `VerticalLayout` and `HorizontalLayout` to `FillAndExpand`

Answer (score 2):

The actual issue is Frame having the default padding of 20 to displaying its child element into frame effects. To fix your issue, by adjusting the padding.